# could not find table: addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am trying to add `rails_admin` to my site. However, when I go to `localhost:3000/admin`, I keep getting this error when attempting to create the first admin account:

```
could not find table 'addresses'
```

I have tried destroying rails_admin and reinstalling, but with no success.

Any help / advice for this would be great!

Comment: Did you run `rake db:migrate`?

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually means that you have a model `Address` but you don't have the table created in the database.

If you have the migration (you probably do if you used a generator to create the model) you just have to run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` in your project's folder.

Be sure that you followed the installation instructions in https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin#installation

Answer (score 0):

There is no table named "Address" in your database. If you have created this, then run the migration, using `rake db:migrate`